# What is the most efficient way to copy a big file from Amazon S3 to the local filesystem using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-s3, transfer

i'm using Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 to copy files from the S3-storage to the local filesystem. What is the most efficient way to copy a big file to the local filesystem (> 1 GB)?

Comment: The Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 documentation describes some streaming operations: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html#zend.service.amazon.s3.streaming . Would it be efficient enough for your needs?

Comment: somehow i managed to overlook that part of the manual. Perfect, thanks!

Comment: OK. I'm converting my comment into a response, for the posterity ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Streaming operations described in the [Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html#zend.service.amazon.s3.streaming). They are intended for this purpose.

Hope that helps,